# Is there a way to force a Deferred() to execute synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Somewhere else in code there's this:

```
function getMyDeferred() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(url, {
        success: function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

In my code, I'm accessing this method and getting a Deferred object. Is there any way to force it to wait at the current line until that deferred has been completed? I realize this is probably going against the whole philosophy of promises and deferreds, but can I do it? Something like this:

```
var deferred = getMyDeferred();

// do something here to ensure we do not proceed to the
// next step until deferred has been resolved

nextStep();
```

Comment: Just use synchronous ajax instead? Ofc it is bad practice and not recommended, but if that's what you want..

Comment: Fabricio, for all intents and purposes, assume that I do not have access to change anything about the first block of code. All I have is the second. What I'm actually doing is unit testing so I need it to wait for a response before it can do anything with that response.

Comment: Oh I see. Most unit test frameworks allow for asynchronous testing though.

Comment: Is wrapping your code in `.then()` too much boilerplate? It's the generally accepted way of working with promises.

Comment: I think you can call defer.done(nextStep);.

Comment: No.  You can't make an async call wait until it's done.  To use async, you have to learn how to code using async tools/techniques.  Start learning.  Also, you're using an anti-pattern with your `getMyDeferred()` function.  You can just do `return $.ajax(...)` since it already returns a promise that is tied to the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 read his previous comments, he said he does not have control over that piece of code.

Comment: @kennypu - He just says "somewhere else in code" and it's posted into his question.  It's an anti-pattern no matter where it is so I think it is worth pointing that out in a comment for the benefit of the community.  It's not like I said that was a solution to the problem.

Comment: There is a way to accomplish what you want, but not when constrained to the way you want to do it.  Ultimately, you shouldn't do it synchronously -- JavaScript doesn't work well this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading people's answers, comments, and doing more research myself, the answer to my original question is simply **no, there isn't**.

I appreciated  Fabrício Matté's comments the most, which pointed out to me something I had just failed to notice at first glance: that the unit testing framework I'm using already has built-in options for asynchronous testing, so I don't need to do what I was outlining here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getMyDeferred().done(nextStep);
```

Comment: There's ZERO reason to use `$.when()` here.  You can just use `deferred.done()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

> I realize this is probably going against the whole philosophy of
>   promises and deferreds

But, you can use the option "**async:false**".

```
function getMyDeferred() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax(url, {
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }
    });
    return deferred;
}
```

By jQuery documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

Comment: See my comment above explaining that, for all intents and purposes, I don't have access to modify that Ajax call.